# Changing a custom post type "has_archive" after registered

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting

Ok, I've seen some similar posts on how to change a custom post type's attributes after it has been registered (in my case, I'm trying to modify a custom post type created by a plugin without modifying the plugin files).

This appears to be working for some properties:

```
function change_wp_object() {
  $object = get_post_type_object('easy-rooms');
  $object->show_in_menu = true;
}
add_action('init','change_wp_object');
```

However, I can't seem to get `has_archive` to change - and it appears to be related to the permalinks. I'm guessing a new rule for `/easy-rooms/` isn't being added.

I've tried adding `flush_rewrite_rules()` (even though it's a bad idea to run it at `init`) but even that doesn't work. Post type is set to public and if I do change the `has_archive` in the plugin code it does work.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would also like to know this. My post type archives won't change from /?post_type=cpt-something to /somethings/

Answer (score 1):

If Your WordPress installation is `4.4.0` or highter, you can filter the arguments pass to the `register_post_type()` function which is eventually pass to the `WP_Post_Type::set_props`

```php
/**
 * Customize Your Post Type args after post type has been registered.
 * 
 * @param array  $args      Array of arguments for registering a post type.
 * @param string $post_type Post type key.
 * 
 * @return array
 */
function wpse_106784_filter_post_type_args( $args, $post_type ) {
    if ( 'your-custom-post-type' === $post_type ) {
        $args['show_in_menu'] = true;
        $args['has_archive'] = true;
        // any other args you need to cange
    }
    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'wpse_106784_filter_post_type_args', 10, 2 );
```

**Edit:**

Don't forget to update your permalink settings after adding the above snippet to your code.
If it's a plugin and your plugin has install method (or activation hook) you can invoke `flush_rewrite_rules()` function there.

Sources:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#source
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post_type/set_props/#source

Comment: I'm trying to use this filter to add `blog` before the slug for the built-in posts, but it seems to do nothing. It works for custom post types, however.

Comment: You should try changing permalink setting from your WordPress dashboard.

Comment: I wanted only posts (but not pages or anything else) to be prepended, so changing permalinks wasn't an option. I ended up solving it by using some custom rewrite rules.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure `'rewrite' => true` is set (to TRUE). Overlooked this converting a CPT without an archive to one with an archive.