# Change plugin's has_archive = true to false?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, archives

When a plugin registers a post type and sets `has_archive` to `true`, is there a way to change it to be false? I don't want the plugin's post type to have an archive, but can't figure out how to turn it off.

A similar questions was asked here, but has no responses: [Changing a custom post type "has_archive" after registered](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106784/changing-a-custom-post-type-has-archive-after-registered)

Comment: When a post type is registered, [rewrite rules are added to handle the archive if it's set to true](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/post.php#L1434). A few ideas - filter `rewrite_rules_array` to remove those rules, add an action to `parse_request` to force archive requests to 404, or remove the plugin's action that registers the post type and register it yourself with your own arguments (could be risky). I'm not sure what would be the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `register_post_type_args` filter (available from WordPress v4.4 on) will allow post type registration arguments to be changed:

```
function wpse206329_custom_post_type_args( $args, $post_type ) {
    if ( $post_type === "my_post_type" ) {
        $args['rewrite'] = false;
    }

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'wpse206329_custom_post_type_args', 20, 2 );
```