# Remove plugin's custom post type archive page and single pages

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, archives, custom-post-type-archives

## The Problem

Hi I am using the plugin: "[Process Steps Template Designer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/process-steps-template-designer/)", I am using the shortcode to add the [vertical process](http://process.cooltimeline.com/#vertical-process) (sort of timeline) to my page, the problem is the text get's cut off after two lines and it adds an automatic excerpt more with a link to the process page.
This brings up two undesired behaviors:

- I do not want any archive/pages for the processes.
- The text gets cut off and displays unnecessary link.

## Information

in one of it's include files it registers a new custom post type called `process_posts`, here is the code:

## Plugin's code

```
<?php

if ( ! class_exists( 'ProcessSteps' ) ) {

    class ProcessSteps {

        /**
         * The Constructor
         */
        public function __construct() {
            // register actions
            add_action( 'init', array( &$this, 'pp_posttype' ) );
            add_filter( 'manage_edit-process_posts_columns', array( &$this, 'add_new_process_posts_columns' ) );
            add_action( 'manage_process_posts_posts_custom_column', array( &$this, 'pp_custom_columns' ), 10, 2 );
            add_action( 'init', array( &$this, 'pp_taxonomy' ), 0 );
            add_action( 'init', array( &$this, 'pp_insert_category' ), 0 );

            add_action( 'save_post_process_posts',array( &$this, 'pp_set_default_object_terms' ),100 ,2 );

            add_filter( 'parse_query',array( &$this, 'pp_convert_id_to_term_in_query' ) );
            add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts',array( &$this, 'pp_filter_post_type_by_taxonomy' ) );
        }

        // END public function __construct())
        // Register Custom Post Type
        function pp_posttype() {

            $labels = array(
                'name' => _x( 'Process Steps', 'Post Type General Name', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'singular_name' => _x( 'Process Infographic', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'menu_name' => __( 'Process Steps', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'name_admin_bar' => __( 'Process Steps', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Item:', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'all_items' => __( 'All Process', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Process', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'new_item' => __( 'New Process', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Process', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'update_item' => __( 'Update Process', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'view_item' => __( 'View Process', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'search_items' => __( 'Search Process', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'not_found' => __( 'Not found', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'cool-timeline' ),
            );
            $args = array(
                'label' => __( 'process_posts', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'description' => __( 'Process Infographic Post Type', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'labels' => $labels,
                'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'author' ),
                'taxonomies' => array(),
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'public' => true,
                'show_ui' => true,
                'show_in_menu' => true,
                'menu_position' => 5,
                'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                'can_export' => true,
                'has_archive' => true,
                'exclude_from_search' => false,
                'publicly_queryable' => true,
                'rewrite' => array(
                    'slug' => 'process_posts',
                ),
                //'menu_icon'=>COOL_TIMELINE_PLUGIN_URL.'/images/cooltimeline.png',
            );
            register_post_type( 'process_posts', $args );
        }

        // Register Custom Taxonomy
        function pp_taxonomy() {

            $labels = array(
                'name' => _x( 'Categories', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'singular_name' => _x( 'Category', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'menu_name' => __( 'Categories', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'all_items' => __( 'All Items', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Item', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Item:', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'new_item_name' => __( 'New Item Name', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Item', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Item', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'update_item' => __( 'Update Item', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'view_item' => __( 'View Item', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove items', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Items', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'search_items' => __( 'Search Items', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'not_found' => __( 'Not Found', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'no_terms' => __( 'No items', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'items_list' => __( 'Items list', 'cool-timeline' ),
                'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'cool-timeline' ),
            );
            $args = array(
                'labels' => $labels,
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'public' => true,
                'show_ui' => true,
                'show_admin_column' => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                'show_tagcloud' => true,
                'query_var' => true,
                //'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'categories' ),
            );
            register_taxonomy( 'process-categories', array( 'process_posts' ), $args );
        }

        public function pp_insert_category() {
            if ( ! term_exists( 'default-process', 'process-categories' ) ) {
                $r = wp_insert_term(
                    'Default process', // the term
                    'process_posts', // the taxonomy
                    array(
                        'description' => 'All process stories.',
                        'slug' => 'default-process',
                        // 'parent' => 0
                    )
                );
            }
        }

        function pp_set_default_object_terms( $post_id, $post ) {
            if ( 'process_posts' === $post->post_type ) {
                if ( 'publish' === $post->post_status ) {
                    $defaults = array(
                        'process-categories' => array( 'default-process' ),
                    );
                    $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $post->post_type );
                    foreach ( (array) $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
                        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy );
                        if ( empty( $terms ) && array_key_exists( $taxonomy, $defaults ) ) {
                            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $defaults[ $taxonomy ], $taxonomy );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function add_new_process_posts_columns( $gallery_columns ) {
            $new_columns['cb'] = '<input type="checkbox" />';

            $new_columns['title'] = _x( 'Title', 'column name', 'cool-timeline' );
            $new_columns['label'] = __( 'Label', 'column name', 'cool-timeline' );
            $new_columns['order'] = _x( 'Order', 'column name', 'cool-timeline' );
            $new_columns['content'] = _x( 'Content', 'column name', 'cool-timeline' );
            $new_columns['category'] = _x( 'Process Category', 'column name', 'cool-timeline' );
            $new_columns['images'] = __( 'Process Image', 'cool-timeline' );
            $new_columns['date'] = _x( 'Published Date', 'column name', 'cool-timeline' );

            return $new_columns;
        }

        function pp_custom_columns( $column, $post_id ) {
            global   $post ;
            switch ( $column ) {
                case 'label':
                    $pp_label = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'pp_post_lbl', true );
                    echo'<p><strong>' . $pp_label . '</strong></p>';
                    break;
                case 'order':
                    $pp_order = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'pp_post_order', true );
                    echo'<p><strong>' . $pp_order . '</strong></p>';
                    break;
                case 'images':
                    $post_image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() );
                    if ( $post_image_id ) {
                        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_image_id, array( 150, 150 ), false );
                        if ( $thumbnail ) {
                            (string) $thumbnail = $thumbnail[0];
                        }
                        echo '<img width="150" height="150" src="' . $thumbnail . '" alt="" />';
                    }
                    break;
                case 'content':
                    echo $content = get_the_excerpt();
                    break;

                /* If displaying the 'genre' column. */
                case 'category':
                    /* Get the genres for the post. */
                    $terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'process-categories' );

                    /* If terms were found. */
                    if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {

                        $out = array();

                        /* Loop through each term, linking to the 'edit posts' page for the specific term. */
                        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                            $out[] = sprintf(
                                '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
                                esc_url(
                                    add_query_arg(
                                        array(
                                            'post_type' => $post->post_type,
                                            'ctl-stories' => $term->slug,
                                        ), 'edit.php'
                                    )
                                ),
                                esc_html( sanitize_term_field( 'name', $term->name, $term->term_id, 'ctl-stories', 'display' ) )
                            );
                        }

                        /* Join the terms, separating them with a comma. */
                        echo join( ', ', $out );
                    } /* If no terms were found, output a default message. */
                    else {
                        _e( '' );
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }


        // end add_custom_rewrite_rule


        /**
     * Display a custom taxonomy dropdown in admin
     * @author coolhappy
     *
     */

        function pp_filter_post_type_by_taxonomy() {
            global $typenow;
            $post_type = 'process_posts'; // change to your post type
            $taxonomy  = 'process-categories'; // change to your taxonomy
            if ( $typenow == $post_type ) {
                $selected      = isset( $_GET[ $taxonomy ] ) ? $_GET[ $taxonomy ] : '';
                $info_taxonomy = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy );
                wp_dropdown_categories(
                    array(
                        'show_option_all' => __( "Show All {$info_taxonomy->label}" ),
                        'taxonomy'        => $taxonomy,
                        'name'            => $taxonomy,
                        'orderby'         => 'name',
                        'selected'        => $selected,
                        'show_count'      => true,
                        'hide_empty'      => true,
                    )
                );
            };
        }



        /**
     * Filter posts by taxonomy in admin
     * @author  coolhappy
     *
     */

        function pp_convert_id_to_term_in_query( $query ) {
            global $pagenow;
            $post_type = 'process_posts'; // change to your post type
            $taxonomy  = 'process-categories'; // change to your taxonomy
            $q_vars    = &$query->query_vars;
            if ( $pagenow == 'edit.php' && isset( $q_vars['post_type'] ) && $q_vars['post_type'] == $post_type && isset( $q_vars[ $taxonomy ] ) && is_numeric( $q_vars[ $taxonomy ] ) && $q_vars[ $taxonomy ] != 0 ) {
                $term = get_term_by( 'id', $q_vars[ $taxonomy ], $taxonomy );
                $q_vars[ $taxonomy ] = $term->slug;
            }
        }


    } //class end

} // main
```

## Things I've tried

I have tried adding this in my child theme's functions.php but achieved no results:

```
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'process_step_post_type_args', 'process_posts' );
function process_step_post_type_args( $args ) {
        $args['has_archive'] = false;
    return $args;
}

function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    global $post;
    if ( $post->post_type === 'process_posts' ) {
        return '';
    }
}
```

## Research

please refer to the [codex documentation of `register_post_type_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_post_type_args/) which was introduced in version 4.4.0 of wordpress

and to [this answer by 'Dave Romsey'](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/239867/130629)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually,this **excerpt more** with link settings automatically applies from your active theme.

In order to fix this problem,Please **add** the below mentioned **filter hook** and **callback function** in your active **child theme** .

```
  function pp_custom_excerpt_length($length) {
        global $post;
        // Set content length only of process posts 
        if ($post->post_type == 'process_posts' && !is_single()) {
            //change it according to your requirement 
            return 100;
        }
        return $length;

    }

  add_filter('excerpt_length', 'pp_custom_excerpt_length', 999);
```

Please let me know if you are unable to fix this issue.

Best Regards,

CoolHappy,

Cool Timeline Team.